# Parallel execution of nested for loop by sharing a class object in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have a class which has methods, variables and it is accessed by the class object.

```
class Error(object):
    spacy_nlp = None
    corenlp = None
    
    def get_spacy_annotations(self, sent):
        sent = self.spacy_nlp.tokenizer.tokens_from_list(sent)
        self.spacy_nlp.tagger(sent)
        self.spacy_nlp.parser(sent)
        return sent
    ...
    ...
```

There is a nested for loop as shown below.

```
for iterator in paragraph:
    paragraphs = iterator['data']
        for line in paragraphs:
            original_text = line['text']
            for hypothesis in line['hypothesis']:
                hypothesis_counter += 1
                ...
            ...
        ...
```

Inside the loop I'm accessing the methods of the above class say `get_spacy_annotations` using the class object (this) as shown below.
[image]

Now I want to reduce the time taken to process this by using the multi-processing with respect to the paragraph. This is not I/O bound rather it is CPU intensive. The variable `paragraph` contains multiple paragraphs which I would like to process concurrently i.e the first for loop.
Along with this I want to share the object of the class across as I do not want to create the multiple objects for each process.

What is the ideal way to achieve this ? Is it possible to do it using `map` or `starmap` ?

Comment: First, it is not clear that the work performed on each paragraph CPU-wise justifies the additional overhead of multiprocessing. Now if this work is mostly I/O bound, then multithreading would be an option. But you have not specified enough details for anyone to be able to venture a guess as to whether either multiprocessing or multithreading might be advantageous. Second, what is it about the processing that would require the `Error` instance to be shared across all processes if you were using multiprocessing? See the [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: Hi @Booboo , thanks for your comment. I've edited the question. It is CPU intensive hence I would like to process it concurrently rather than multi-threading. Since there are few other methods inside the Error which is being used within the loops I want to share a single object across multiple processes.

Comment: It's still not clear to me (I am not familiar with `spacy`) why you need to share a common object to process individual paragraphs in parallel. I was wondering whether the state of this object gets updated  in such a way that would influence how another paragraph is processed. But if that is the case, then you should look into turning this into a *managed* object. See [this topic](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multiprocessing%20manager#module-multiprocessing.managers).

Comment: But method calls to such a managed object run as individual threads in a separate process. This is not conducive to doing multiple CPU-intensive operations in parallel unless `spacy` is releasing the Global Interpreter Lock when one of its CPU-intensive methods gets called (the method would have to implemented in `C` or `C++` to do that).